# How to get Term Frequency value from Weka?

Tags: java, nlp, weka

I am using **StringToWordVector** to generate a TDM using tweets. Here is the **Instances** output after running through the **StringToWordVector** filter.

```
@data

{0 1,1 1,2 1,3 1,4 1,5 1,6 1,7 1,8 1,9 1,10 1,11 1,15 1,16 1,29 1,30 1,31 1,35 1,36 }

{17 1,18 1,19 1,20 1,21 1,22 1,23 1,24 1,25 1,26 1,27 1,28 1,32 1,3}

{12 1,13 1,14 1,41 1,42 1,43 1,50 1,51 2,52 1,63 1,64 1,65 1,72 1,73 1,74 1,83 1,84 }
```

How do I get the Term frequency values?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is Sparse ARFF data section, the non-zero attributes are explicitly identified by attribute number and their value stated (the value is the term frequency). Each instance is surrounded by curly braces, and the format for each entry is:    where index is the attribute index (starting from 0). You can find out more about this here: http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/arff.html

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to get a count of this term freq across all instances in the dataset? In other words, I want to know how many times the attribute identified by index pos 3 appears in the dataset?